# F# Subfolder Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

If I add two subfolders with the same name in an F# project I get this error:

[image: F# Folder Error]

The folder strucure is:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Test\File1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="SubFolder\Test\File2.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: It appears the subfolders are not at the same level, which is fine in Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you dont have in your project

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Folder1\File1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="SubFolder\Test\File2.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Folder1\another.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but instead

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Folder1\File1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Folder1\another.fs" />
    <Compile Include="SubFolder\Test\File2.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(contiguous folders mentions)

This causes a bug which has been reported.
If you can isolate and reproduce a bug, please send it to fsbugs@microsoft.com, the team really looks after those pbs.